# Отображение гугл карты на сайте по адресу

Tags: google-maps

Хочу встроить гугл карту на сайт, но чтобы метка отображалась по адресу, а не по координатам. Так как они будут создаваться динамически, и известны нам только адреса.

Как это сделать? Или нужно обязательно получать координаты?
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: C помощью геокодера можно конвертировать адреса в координаты и наоборот

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro